# Prevent encoding info message "Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources."

Tags: maven, utf-8

Every time I run any maven commands, I always get an info message about how Maven will use UTF-8 encoding to copy filtered resources. It looks like this:

```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ my-project-name ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
```

I have tried specifying UTF-8 as the encoding in several different places to no avail.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <!-- ... -->

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Why do I still get these info messages? Is there any way to suppress them? It's not a huge deal but I find it mildly annoying.

Comment: First if you use the properties to define the encoding you can omit the configuration for encoding in maven-resources-plugin. Apart from that you can't prevent the output because it's done by the plugin itself on INFO level... The other question is: What is the problem with it?

Comment: That's what I suspected. I just really appreciate clean output from my tools, and I find no value in the message. It seems like something I should be able to suppress. Maybe I'll look into submitting a pull request :)